# Force the title to be single-spaced

Tags: spacing, formatting

My title takes up two lines. However, for some reason it gets double spaced. How can I force single-spacing in the title?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An example of how you produce your document is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use the standard procedure for creating titles, you can use the following fix (though it's needless in this particular example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\preto\@title{\singlespacing}}% in case it isn't single spaced
\makeatother

\title{A very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
\author{MyseteryMan}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output]